# What do are group permission missing on new directories?

Tags: permissions, defaults, mkdir

Normally when I make a directory with `mkdir` the permissions I expect are 751 or 755. However for some reason when new files are created, even in a users home directory, they are set to 700.

What controls the default permissions on new files and what kind of configuration change led to this happening?

Comment: you need to understand `umask`, read `man umask`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Tejas mentioned, you need to understand `umask` and its values for changing the default permissions.

I recommend you read [this](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19683-01/817-1658/userconcept-95347/index.html) article so you'll understand how to use it properly.

In addition, you should know that it's not permanent, so after rebooting your system the `umask` value you've set will be gone. To set it in a permanent way, you need to write a new `umask` value in your shell’s configuration file (`~/.bashrc` which is executed for interactive non-login shells, or `~/.bash_profile` which is executed for login shells).

Good Luck

Comment: Thanks @Tejas and Farazx, I learned a lot about umask, apparently someone changed it at some point and didn't tell any users.